# How might I create a Form that can interact allow me to view/edit a 'ticket' list item and then add related 'action' list items

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create a basic ticketing system that will allow me to interact with a 'ticket' list item that allows me to add one or more 'actions' for that ticket. My major constraint is that I am unable to buy PowerApps, otherwise I would use that to do this.

However, I do have SharePoint lists, the Microsoft or SharePoint Forms and the use of Power Automate, but not the premium one.

A ticket list item would be created through an integration with the list that originated from a system that manages product payments. 14 days after a scheduled payment fails, details of the missed/overdue payment and the contact details of the customer to call are used to create a ticket.

The ticket gets assigned to someone and their updates to it (other than the status) is to add related actions that they have either taken already (an outbound call with a note to say they left a message, inbound call, etc.) or an action to follow up that sets the action date in the future, so that the action become a 'to do' rather than what has already happened.

Very basic parent 'ticket' list with ticket_id and child 'actions' list with ticket_id as the relationship key.

Is this something anyone has attempted before? Maybe a form with a sub-form and power automate doing something but, really don't know where to begin. I prototyped exactly this in PowerApps in all of about an hour but although it's exactly right, no appetite to spend the money on the Premium license lol.

Any advice on this greatly appreciated.

Here's some example data in case anyone has an idea to try, thank you:

Ticket record

ticket_id, ticket_number, brand, customer_number, customer_name, amount_owed, payment_fail_reason, mobile_number, email, assigned_to, status, created, modified
ABC-1234, 1011, ABC, 12345-01, Joe Bloggs, 235.72, CARD PAYMENT DECLINED, 021 456 7890, joe.bloggs@me.com, Rosie, WORK IN PROGRESS, 2024-03-04T10:32:04, 2024-03-05T15:38:22

Action record
action_id, ticket_id, action_type, action_date, action_notes, created, modified
DEF-4456, ABC-1234, OUTBOUND CALL, 2024-03-06, left a message, 2024-03-06T09:22:45, 2024-03-06T09:22:45